# randomize the order of text lines in a .tex file

Tags: input, random-numbers

I need to create an environment (let's call it `randomizer`) that randomly changes the order of its lines, which may contain any text or latex commands (assume without verifying that they don't break across lines).

For example, I have several `tex` files, each containing one problem and I want to generate a set of problems put in a random order. Then I would use

```
\begin{randomizer}
  \input{problem1}
  \input{problem2}
  \input{problem3}
  \input{problem4}
\end{randomizer}
```

I want also to be able to control the random process, by having the possibility to specify a seed number for the generator.

Comment: You could take a look to [examdesign](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/examdesign): _multiple versions of the same test can be generated automatically, with the ordering of questions within each section randomly permuted so as to minimize cheating;_

Comment: I already have the problems written in their specific format and using `examdesign` would mean to rewrite them.

Comment: It's not only to use examdesign, but also to look, how they solved it there - perhaps you could use the same logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution based on the RANOMIZE-IN-PLACE procedure in the [CLRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms).  The procedure is defined as

```
n = A.length
for i=1 to n
   swap A[i] with A[random(i,n)]
```

(CLRS does not like `end for`, so we do not use it either).

TeX code uses `random.tex` by Donald Arseneau (should be in your distribution).  This code puts in 10 macros `\csname num0\endcsname`, `\csname num1\endcsname`, ... some random permutation of numbers 0..9 (I used macros instead of counters to save the latter).  You can use this code to write something like `\expandafter\input{file\csname num0\endcsname}`, `\expandafter\input{file\csname num1\endcsname}` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{random}
\begin{document}
\newcount\number
\newcount\randomnum

% Put 0..9 into \num0..\num9
\number=0
\loop\ifnum\the\number<10\relax
\expandafter\edef\csname num\the\number\endcsname{\the\number}
\advance\number by 1
\repeat

% Randomize
\number=0
\loop\ifnum\the\number<10\relax
\setrannum{\randomnum}{\the\number}{9}  % Random number between \number and 9
\edef\tmpnum{\csname num\the\number\endcsname}
\expandafter\edef\csname num\the\number\endcsname{\csname
  num\the\randomnum\endcsname} 
\expandafter\edef\csname num\the\randomnum\endcsname{\tmpnum}
\advance\number by 1
\repeat

% Print the results:
\number=0
\loop\ifnum\the\number<10\relax
Macro \textbackslash num\the\number\space contains \expandafter\csname
num\the\number\endcsname
\advance\number by 1\relax\par
\repeat
% To input in random order files file0.tex, file1.tex, file2.tex,... 
% use instead
% \number=0
% \loop\ifnum\the\number<10\relax
% \expandafter\input{file\csname num\the\number\endcsname}
% \advance\number by 1\relax
% \repeat

\end{document}
```

See `random.tex` documentation about seeding the generator.

Output example:

```
Macro \num0 contains 7
Macro \num1 contains 1
Macro \num2 contains 9
Macro \num3 contains 3
Macro \num4 contains 6
Macro \num5 contains 8
Macro \num6 contains 2
Macro \num7 contains 5
Macro \num8 contains 4
Macro \num9 contains 0
```

Comment: How can this be applied when instead of sequential filenames I have some arbitrary filenames?

Comment: You can put the filenames in an "array": `\def\Input#1{\ifcase#1\input{first}\or\input{second}\or...\fi}`.  Thus the command `\Input{0}` inputs `first.tex`, etc. Then your last loop should call `\expandafter\Input{\csname num\the\number\endcsname}`

Comment: You can set the seed with `\randomi42\relax % set Seed to 42`. Else it is initialized in dependence on date and time. See sourcecode of [`random`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/random).

Answer (score 4):

If you have `luatex`, you can also use lua.  This uses the same shuffling method as Boris's answer, but in lua. Call `lualatex` with the following file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\newcommand\SeedRnd[1][os.time()]{\directlua{rndseed = #1; math.randomseed(rndseed)}}
\newcommand\RndSeed{\directlua{tex.print(rndseed)}}

\SeedRnd %Takes an optional parameter if you want a specific random seed

\newcommand\RndOrderInput[1]{%
\luaexec{
local table = {#1}
function shuffle(t)
  local n = \#t
  while n > 1 do
    local k = math.random(n)
    t[n], t[k] = t[k], t[n]
    n = n - 1
  end
  return t
end
for k,v in pairs(shuffle(table)) do tex.print("\string\\input{" .. v .. "}") end
}}

\begin{document}
Random seed: \RndSeed %so you will be able to recreate this order. 
\RndOrderLoad{'file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4'}
\end{document}
```

Note that the file names have to be written as lua strings, that is `'file1'` or `"file1"`, not just `file1`.