# How to iteratively build \ifcase

Tags: macros, loops

Although I've been a LaTeX user for years, this is the first time that I've been unable to find the answer to a LaTeX issue, so this is my first posted question.

I'm defining a command (`\QPreparation`) that will redefine the command `\QInput`.  The command `\QInput{N}` should input code into my document based on number N that I send it.  With each call of the `\QPreparation` command, I want the base path `\QInput` looks in to change as well as the total number of cases that `\QInput` will consider.  The input files are named "C0.tex","C1.tex","C2.tex",... so that in redefining `\QInput`, the new file options are easy to update.

In the code that I've been working on (below), the 2 inputs to `\QPreparation` are (a) the base path to update `\QInput` and (b) the number of cases that I want `\QInput` to consider.

Because my next step is to modify the `\QPreparation` command so that the calls `\QInput{0}`, `\QInput{1}`, ... `\QInput{N}` load all N files in a random order, I **DO NOT** believe that it is feasible to make `\QPreparation` define `\QInput` in a manner like `\input{#1/C##1.tex}`.

If you are curious about how I plan to do the randomization, consider  [randomize the order of text lines in a .tex file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40815/randomize-the-order-of-text-lines-in-a-tex-file) .

It seems to me that the easiest way to solve this problem is to define `\QInput` with an `\ifcase` that is generated by a loop.  The sample code (below) shows my attempt at this, but the additional `\or` in the loop throws errors such as:

```
! Extra \or. \iterate ->\ifnum \the \QIternum <4\relax \or                                                \input {./Q1/C\the \QIternum ....
```

My sample code:

```
\newcommand{\QPreparation}[2]{%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname QInput\endcsname[1]{%
    \ifcase##1
      \input{#1/C0.tex}
      \QIternum=1
      \loop\ifnum\the\QIternum<#2\relax
        \or
        \input{#1/C\the\QIternum.tex}
      \advance\QIternum by 1
      \repeat
    \fi
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863).

Comment: If I understand your description, after `\Qpreparation{foo}{2}` the command `\Qinput` should be defined like in the code
   `\renewcommand{\Qinput}[1]{\ifcase#1\relax \input{foo/C0.tex}\or\input{foo/C1.tex}\or\input{foo/C2.tex}\fi}` Am I right?

Comment: essentially, yes, you are correct

Comment: why the `\ifcase` rather than simply `\renewcommand{\Qinp‌​ut}[1]{\input{foo/C#1.tex}}` ?

Comment: The code is a work in process, and the next step precludes that simple solution.  The next step involves shuffling the file list so that `\Qinput{1}` will not give `\input{fooC1.tex}` but instead `\input{fooCN.tex}` where N is random and determined by the shuffling.  I've already found info on how to ``shuffle'' lines of tex code (see main body of text).  If I can make the \ifcase work, then I can reach the goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The replacement text is not executed when the replacement text is absorbed.

You can build the macro in an indirect way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\QInput}{} % initialization

\makeatletter
\newcount\QIteration
\newcommand{\QPreparation}[2]{%
  \QIteration=\z@
  \gdef\tempa{\ifcase####1\relax\input{#1/C0.tex}}%
  \loop\ifnum\QIteration<#2
    \advance\QIteration\@ne
    \edef\tempb{%
      \expandafter\noexpand\csname or\endcsname
      \noexpand\input{#1/C\the\QIteration.tex}%
    }%
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\tempa\expandafter{\tempb}%
  \repeat
  \g@addto@macro\tempa{\fi}
  \def\tempb{\renewcommand\QInput[1]}%
  \expandafter\tempb\expandafter{\tempa}
}
\makeatother
\QPreparation{foo}{5}

\show\QInput
```

The `\show` command will output

```
> \QInput=\long macro:
#1->\ifcase #1\relax \input {foo/C0.tex}\or \input {foo/C1.tex}\or \input {foo/
C2.tex}\or \input {foo/C3.tex}\or \input {foo/C4.tex}\or \input {foo/C5.tex}\fi
 .
```

which seems to be what you want.

It's necessary to hide `\or` in the loop, because otherwise we'd get a “misplaced `\or`” error.

An alternative without global definitions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\QInput}{} % initialization

\makeatletter
\newcount\QIteration
\toks@={}
\newcommand{\QPreparation}[2]{%
  \QIteration=\z@
  \toks@={\ifcase##1\relax\input{#1/C0.tex}}%
  \loop\ifnum\QIteration<#2
    \advance\QIteration\@ne
    \edef\temp{%
      \expandafter\noexpand\csname or\endcsname
      \noexpand\input{#1/C\the\QIteration.tex}%
    }%
    \toks@=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\toks@\temp}%
  \repeat
  \toks@=\expandafter{\the\toks@\fi}%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\renewcommand\noexpand\QInput[1]{\the\toks@}%
  }\x
}
\makeatother
\QPreparation{foo}{5}

\show\QInput
```

An equivalent solution if `xparse` is used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_strickland_temp_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\QPreparation}{mm}
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_strickland_temp_tl
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 0 } { 1 } { #2 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_strickland_temp_tl { {##1}{\input{#1/C##1.tex}} }
   }
  \use:x
   {
    \exp_not:N \DeclareDocumentCommand \exp_not:N \QInput { m }
     {
      \exp_not:N \int_case:nn { ####1 } { \exp_not:V \l_strickland_temp_tl }
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Answer (score 7):

An alternative way of building up the ifcase

```
\documentclass{article}


\def\QInput{}
\def\afterfi#1\fi{\fi#1}
\def\QPreparation#1#2{\bgroup
\let\or\relax\let\input\relax
\XQPreparation{#1}{#2}%
\edef\x{\egroup\def\noexpand\QInput####1{%
  \noexpand\ifcase####1\relax\input{#1/C0.tex}\QInput\noexpand\fi}}%
\x
}
\def\XQPreparation#1#2{%
\ifnum#2>0 \afterfi
\edef\QInput{\or\input{#1/C#2.tex}\QInput}%
\XQPreparation{#1}{\the\numexpr#2-1\relax}%
\fi}


\begin{document}
\QPreparation{foo}{5}

\show\QInput
\end{document}
```

produces

```
> \QInput=macro:
#1->\ifcase #1\relax \input {foo/C0.tex}\or \input {foo/C1.tex}\or \input {foo/
C2.tex}\or \input {foo/C3.tex}\or \input {foo/C4.tex}\or \input {foo/C5.tex}\fi
 .
l.23 \show\QInput
```